# Issue updating MudBlazor component in OnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I'm trying to recover some data asynchronously from localStorage then activate a specific tab from MudTabs component if data is found.

```html
<MudTabs @ref="tabs">
  <MudTabPanel>
  </MudTabPanel>
  <MudTabPanel>
  </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>
```

The problems come from my method OnAfterRenderAsync who doesn't work updating the MudBlazor component state, here is the code:

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    var result = await protectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("Call");
    if (result.Success)
    {
      tabs.ActivatePanel(1);
      StateHasChanged();
    }
  }
  //return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

I tested a previous version of it who worked pretty well but i cannot use the await operator inside of it, the method not being asynchronously:

```cs
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    tabs.ActivatePanel(1);
  }
  return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

I didn't found what is specifically the difference between returning the base method and calling the StateHasChanged. When using the StateHasChanged method the active panel remain on the 0 index.

If you have any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what's the problem here , are saying that the first method  " async Task OnAfterRenderAsync" does not work  and "Task OnAfterRenderAsync" does ?

Comment: Exactly when i'm trying the "async Task OnAfterRenderAsync" my MudBlazor component doesn't update, in the other case with the method "Task OnAfterRenderAsync" the component update well. And unfortunatly i cannot switch the code inside OnInitializedAsync because i'm in prerendered mode.

Comment: what version of dotnet are you using ?

Comment: i'm with the latest version .Net 6

Answer (score 0):

I specified the ID on the tab to be numeric, same value as the index of the tab.

(It worked for me as a workaround on .net 7.0.3 and MudBlazor 6.1.9)

```html
<MudTabs @ref="@Tabs">
    <MudTabPanel ID="@(0)">
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel ID="@(1)">
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>
```

```cs
@code {
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    var activeTab = await LocalStorageService.GetItemAsync<int?>("ActiveTab"); 
    if (activeTab != null) {
        Tabs!.ActivatePanel(activeTab.Value);
    }
  }
}
```